# Is there a way to enter a specific INTEGER (for example, 3) and have python print same amount of characters (like, entering 3 and printing "aaa" out)

Tags: python

If i entered an integer numeral, like 3, I would like the computer to print the same amount of a particular character, in this case, a. So I want the output to look something like this: (Sorry I am extremely new to python)

```
> Input: Input a number: 7

> Output: aaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```py
# take inputs
numOfTimes= int(input("Enter a number : "))
chrc = input("Enter the character : ")

# build the string you want
text = chrc*numOfTimes
# You can multiply a string from integer to repeat it.

print(text)
```

Example:

```
Enter a number : 5
Enter the character : A
AAAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very easy in fact:

```
num = int(input("Input a number: "))
print('a'*num)
```

You may want to verify that the input is an integer, though:

```
def get_num(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            d = int(input(msg))
            if d > 0:
                return d
            else:
                print('Please enter a positive integer.')
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a positive integer.')

num = get_num('Input a number: ')
print('a'*num)
```